# What is the purpose of the ReaderID attribute in <ext:JsonReader>?

Tags: .net, extjs, ext.net, coolite

I'm learning how to use Coolite at the moment. I'm trying to use the `Store` element but I don't know what the `ReaderID` attribute of the `JsonReader` does?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without checking specifically I would assume that the 'ReaderID' property has the same benefits as any 'ID' property, in that it gives a unique reference to the element.

This is often so that you can find it by the ID and perform functions directly upon a specific instance, rather than finding it by type or having to loop through all the items on a page and locate the specific instance you're after.

Answer (score 2):

The `.ReaderID` property is a little confusing. Here's the definition:

> Name of the property within a row object that contains a record identifier value. Defaults to id

Basically, its the name of property in the data item which should be used as the "ID" for that row.

For example, if your 'Customer' object has a `"CustomerID"` property, then you should set the `.ReaderID` property to `"CustomerID"`.

FYI, as of Ext.NET v1.x, the `.ReaderID` property has been renamed to `.IDProperty`.

More information available at (client-side docs):

http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-3.3.1/docs/?class=Ext.data.JsonReader&member=idProperty

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification Geoffrey, makes a lot more sense how you put it. The client side 'id' was always a bit weird for me so I'd like to know that I could set it at databind to something meaningful to the row server side, IDProperty makes a lot more semantic sense personally!